# Right-margin marks in VS2010 text editors

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In VS2008, you could enable right-margin marks by creating a string registry entry named `Guides` under `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Text Editor`.  It also worked with the express editions: replace *VisualStudio* with *VCExpress* or *VCSExpress*.

The value I had was: `RGB(192,192,192) 80, 100` which gave me light gray lines at columns 80 and 100.

I've just tried (and failed) to set them up in VC++2010 Express and VC#2010 Express; does anyone know if they're still supported?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not out of the box, but...

Go to "tools\extension manager".

Click "online gallery".

Type "guides" in the search box.

The first hit is 'editor guidelines', an extension that reads the same registry keys as before.  I think there are other extensions in the gallery for it too, maybe.

Here's the link & description of the extension:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/0fbf2878-e678-4577-9fdb-9030389b338c

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  It looks as if they won't work with the Express editions (that I use at home), but I'll look into them at work.

Comment: Paul also wrote an extension that adds menu items for it: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/7f2a6727-2993-4c1d-8f58-ae24df14ea91

Note also that you need to use the *10.0* registry hive instead of 9.0 that you used for VS2008 (and mention in your question).

Answer (score 5):

Or, better yet, get Microsoft's Productivity Power Tools from the same place (tools/extension manager/online gallery search for guides).  Column guides are just one of the many super-cool features this adds to the VS environment...

Answer (score 2):

Visual Assist X also has a feature for this, under

Visual Assist X Options -> Advanced -> Display -> Display indicator after column ....